# Hitting directly a controller in codeigniter and getting json response

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, get

I am doing this in my codeigniter controller

```
public function getprice($origin,$destination){
    $this->load->model("flights");
    $query['data']=$this->flights->giveprice($origin,$destination);  //model gives fine result
     $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => $query['data'])));   //data is printed correctly


   }
```

I have hitted this url with the exact this url :-

```
localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/booking/getprice?origin="Karachi"&destination="Lahore"
```

and i am getting this as response:-

```
 <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>
<p>Type: ArgumentCountError</p>
<p>Message: Too few arguments to function Booking::getprice(), 0 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeIgniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 2 expected</p>
<p>Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeIgniter/application/controllers/Booking.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 22</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>
<p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeIgniter/index.php
    <br />
        Line: 315
    <br />
        Function: require_once
</p>
```

Another function of mine without parameters runs fine, but when parameters ("GET") are involved it says "too few arguements given", I am providing 2 arguments. Please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have call function using get parameters.
But calling in codeigniter is different than ordinary function calling.
Example: http://localhost/project/main/getproduct/24/45

See this
[Passing multiple variables in URL using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766010/passing-multiple-variables-in-url-using-codeigniter)

Comment: yeah but what if I want to call like this ....localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/booking/getprice?origin=Karachi&destination=Lahore and not like.. localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/booking/getprice/Karachi/Lahore ???

Comment: Than in controller you need to give $GET['origin'] but when you pass parameter you can easily gives $origin

Comment: It gives "undefined variable $GET"

Comment: Ohh sorry it is $_GET

Answer (score 1):

You have call function using get parameters.
But calling in codeigniter is different than ordinary function calling when parameters are given.
Example : 
localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/booking/getprice/Karachi/Lahore

See this: [Passing multiple variables in URL using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766010/passing-multiple-variables-in-url-using-codeigniter)